# Disable New Relic Script for one template

Tags: email, javascript, html-email, settings, newrelic

Is there any way to disable the New Relic script tag from being output in a single template?

EllisLab's docs say you can disable it via the control panel overall, but I really need it removed just from a single template (which becomes an email template).

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/monitoring/new-relic.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the New Relic PHP api??

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/configuration/php-agent-api

Specifically

```
newrelic_disable_autorum (  )
```

Perhaps if you turned PHP (output) on in your header embeds/templates, you could do something like this before your doctype declaration:

```
<?php
if (extension_loaded('newrelic') &&
    "{segment_1}/{segment_2}" == "email/contact")
{
    newrelic_disable_autorum();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way of doing this currently, but I can add it to our list of things to think about. Maybe a hidden config where you can add template group and template pairs:

```
$config['newrelic_template_ignore'] = array(
    'template_group/template',
    'other_template_group/*'
);
```